# Graph issue when y-axis has only '0' as values in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have the following chart

http://jsfiddle.net/hcJjX/2/

If you notice the y-axis values are always '0' here. But the line is drawn in the middle of the chart. However, I want the line to be drawn on top of the 'x-axis' as follows (as it would be if there were atleast one non-zero value):

http://jsfiddle.net/hcJjX/2/

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The chart is unable to calculate a sensible y-axis scale as it has no min/max values to go on. If you tell it a max, then it renders as you want:

```
 yAxis: {
    endOnTick: false,
    minPadding: 0,
    max:1
},
```

If you don't want to iterate through your data to work out if all the points are zero, let highcharts do the work for you as it has to calculate the min/max anyway. You can call getExtremes to work out the max y value, and use setExtremes to force a particular max:

```
chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            load: function (event) {
                var extremes = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
                if (extremes.dataMax == 0) {
                    extremes.max = 1;
                    this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CbwrB/

Comment: Setting the max value for each chart is not a proper solution.Say I have a huge data set with 1000s of points and I cannot be iterating through the same for determining the max point. Is there any other solution which I can go by with?I can set the min value as 0 though

Comment: Iterating through the data isn't that big a deal. Highcharts does it in order to plot the graph anyway. If you don't want to do it, see my updated post for a way to ask highcharts for the min/max values in the load event handdler.

Answer (score 0):

Here, column with type date time values. So, please go with "null" instead of 0.

Like given below,

series: [{ 
            data: [[1373308338468,null],[1373308938471,null]]
        }]

But workaround at yAxis by minRange to "0.01"

Example,

yAxis: { min: 0, minRange: 0.01 }

Answer (score -1):

if you wan to see the graph even when the value is zero you can go with

```
plotOptions: {
 series: {
   minPointLength: 3
 }
},
```

here is your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hcJjX/4/

Hope this will be of use

Comment: Actually the issue I had was the line appearing in the middle of the chart. Please see the example below:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/hcJjX/2/) . However, their suggestion is to set the min and max value which may not be possible always.Atleast I can specify the min value as 0 but its not possible to compute the max value for each chart. It would be cumbersome to iterate through the data set.